# Primefaces fileDownload non-english file names corrupt

Tags: primefaces, download, filenames, non-english

I am using Primefaces 3.2. I've got problems with using primefaces fileDownload. I can upload the files and keep their non-english name on the server (in my case this is Russian). However, when I use p:fileDownload to download the uploaded files I cannot use Russian letters since they get corrupt. It seems that the DefaultStreamedContent class constructor accepts only Latin letters.
I am doing everything according to the showcase on the primefaces website as shown below.

```
public FileDownloadController() {          
    InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("/images/optimusprime.jpg");  
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg", "downloaded_optimus.jpg");  
}
```

Any ideas how I can solve my problem?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I'm swamped, but can you link a file as an example? I ripped this servlet apart 4 months ago and I'd be happy to run it through the debugger if I have something to use.

Comment: You mean the file I used? How can I link it here? I used .docx file with russian name. If it's not difficult for you, you can create any .doc or .docx file and give it a name in russian "Тестовый файл" (Test file).

Comment: Sorry for the delay: I wasn't able to recreate, however here's where you want to look:
http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/webapp/MultipartRequest.java

Basically it is built on top of ApacheFileUpload and it is using that method (parseRequest) to do it. Also, make sure that your char-set is correct and it isn't streaming to ASCII or something silly when it saves.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [fixed in the upcoming PrimeFaces 6.2](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1312), but for earlier versions the fix below needs to be applied. In a link in the comments below a reference to a PrimeFaces issue was posted which contains info that the fix below does work for Chrome, IE and Opera but not for FireFox (no version mentioned, nor is 'Edge' mentioned)

**Workaround**

Try to encode your file name in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME format ([URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)).

Example:

```
public StreamedContent getFileDown () {
        // Get current position in file table
        this.currentPosition();
        attachments = getAttachments();
        Attachment a = getAttachmentByPosition( pos, attachments );

        FileNameMap fileNameMap = URLConnection.getFileNameMap();
        // Detecting MIME type
        String mimeType = fileNameMap.getContentTypeFor(a.getAttachmentName());
        String escapedFilename = "Unrecognized!!!";
        try {
            // Encoding
            escapedFilename = URLEncoder.encode(a.getAttachmentName(), "UTF-8").replaceAll(
                    "\\+", "%20");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {         
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Preparing streamed content
        fileDown = new DefaultStreamedContent( new ByteArrayInputStream( a.getAttachment() ),
                mimeType, escapedFilename);
        return fileDown;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine for me with russian and ukrainian file names.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, however the displayed name which I get through the name property of the DefaultStreamedContent gets also url encoded.

Comment: @Nurzhan Do not quite understand what you meant. For displaying file names on the page, I get the name of the file directly from `Attachment` object. If you need to decode this format use [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

Comment: Hopefully will be fixed in PF eventually: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/149

Comment: In this link to the PrimeFaces Github is additional information: It does not seem to work on FireFox (no versions mentioned, so your milage might vary). But this issue is marked as a duplicate of another issue https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1312 which states it will be fixed in the upcoming 6.2 release