# Export file with Arabic name from PrimeFaces on Firefox

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download, arabic

We have been facing a problem that file with expected Arabic name exported from PrimeFaces has blanks (as name) instead of text followed by the extension like " .csv". File's contents are displayed in Arabic as they should be. We have Apache-Tomcat 6.0.29 server. I debugged and found that the file has the name in Arabic till the return statement (Java code given below) but couldn't debug after that. Tried the solution given in the accepted answer here [Primefaces fileDownload non-english file names corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407156/primefaces-filedownload-non-english-file-names-corrupt) but it didn't work for me because I was using Firefox. We had already set the property of **URIEncoding="UTF-8"** in **connector** tag inside **server.xml**.

XHTML:

```
<p:commandLink id="export" ajax="false" > Export
<p:fileDownload value="#{groupView.export}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Java:

```
 public StreamedContent getExport() {

    String content = "Any text in Arabic or English";

    // send CSV file to browser
    InputStream is;
    StreamedContent file = null;
    try {
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "application/csv", "المشاركات.csv","UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file; //FILE NAME IS IN ARABIC TILL HERE
    }
```

PS: I tried creating file with Arabic name through plain Java and it worked.

Comment: Click the link to the other question. It fails, please correct it. And please try to make an [mcve]. Saves others work in trying to reproduce

Comment: Edited. Link is working now :)

Comment: I will change the code snippets

Comment: I have edited the code. Just copy paste in the existing files will do.

Comment: You still **don't** url encode the name like stated in the accepted answer... Why?

Comment: I tried that too. But that didn't work

Comment: Encoding changed the name from blanks to something like B@6A451c

Comment: Then you did something wrong... that is the object hash!

Comment: See how you question is _not good_? I have to ask all sorts of clarifications that you could and **should** have added upfront. The last statements are the most important **and effectively your 'quedtion'**: URLEndoding a filename fails and results in....

Comment: `String fileName = URLEncoder.encode("المشاركات", "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20"); 
file = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "application/csv", fileName+ ".csv","UTF-8");`

 I tried this and resulted in percent encoding. B@6A451c is for some other solution I tried (my mistake).

Comment: Thanks for sending down the wrong path... Did you fully read oher Q/A including the comments and everything in the links that is in the comments? And all relevant links in there? Tried the latest PF snapshot from source in github

Comment: Sorry for that. I did read them and many others before posting this. Tried all sorts of solutions.

Comment: I edited the commet above a little, please read again. There is lots more info in there that you also don't talk about. Cheers... that's all from me... good luck further

Comment: Next time, read, read, read, like I did for you. You are welcome

Comment: Thanks! I must have been half asleep while reading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primefaces fileDownload non-english file names corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407156/primefaces-filedownload-non-english-file-names-corrupt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepted answer in the post I shared works perfectly for most of the browsers but Firefox. To over come this, I used `contentDisposition` property in `p:fileDownload` tag. This syntax is a bit weird but it works. Asterisk and single quotes are part of it.

```
<p:fileDownload value="#{groupView.export}" contentDisposition="inline; filename*=utf-8''%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%A7%D8%AA.csv"/>
```

In normal situations, this encoded text would be passed from the bean but I have added for clarity.